# Rewriting one page on base url

Tags: .htaccess

Basically, I want to create a rewrite rule again but for another URL,

I already have this
http://site.com/game/title

I want to rewrite a new URL to this
http://site.com/game-test/title-test

I've tried the following but it's failed

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)-test/([^/]*)-test /game_details.php?eid=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading slash as mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess are applied per directory. You should also have end anchor `$` in your regex

So this should work for `/game-test/title-test`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-test/([^-]+)-test/?$ /game_details.php?eid=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### Recommended Read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will work, but try both:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)-test/([^/]*)-test /game_details.php?eid=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)-test/([^-]*)-test /game_details.php?eid=$1&id=$2 [L]
```